# How to revert back to previous state from current updated state in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I updated my Ubuntu 12.10 . after updating it asked for reboot, I rebooted my system. After rebooting my system it shows only blank (black) screen , No mouse cursor ,No terminal Nothing. I want to revert back to my previous state of system just before the update happened.

(I remembered some packages installed while updating they are XORG ,Linux-header,etc..)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your post whether you have installed proprietary graphics driver manually (not from software center/addtional driver)

It also seems the updated software contain a new kernel. So removing such update, I won't recommend at all. Also in near future you will have problem updating.

If the above two statement are correct. Please note, you need to reinstall the graphics driver again for the new kernel.

To verify, on grub menu (Press `shift` while booting if you use ubuntu as only OS), 
go to `Advanced` option and boot to any older kernel listed there. IF this works flawlessly, then update your graphics driver as mentioned in the following question.

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

[Enter recovery mode from GRUB](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode). Can you log into your account? If so, make a backup of your files and check your error logs under `/var/log` so you can tell what's happening. You can not revert an update, but you can, and should, update again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I want to delete those packages who are recently updated and want to install their previous versions which was installed in my OS.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove PACKAGE` to remove. As I already mentioned, you CAN NOT roll back an update. Once you install something it's final. If you do as I said you'll update again, and luckly any buggy packages will be replaced with a working one. If you want to downgrade packages you'll have to download individual `.deb` files for the version you want of each package or the source if a `.deb` is not available and compile it. You can edit your `sources.list` to a repository that provides older versions of the packages installed, but I wouldn't recommend it.